# How to not add duplicate list values but instead add a counter to count each item?

Tags: python

```
elif int(groceriesInput) in range(len(groceries)+1):
    optionSelect = input("\nAdd " + (groceries[int(groceriesInput)- 1][0]) + " to the cart? (y or n): ")
    if optionSelect == "y" or optionSelect == "Y":
        if groceries[int(groceriesInput)-1] in cart:
            os.system('cls')
        else:
            os.system('cls')
            cart.append(groceries[int(groceriesInput)- 1])
```

How would I add a counter before each item without adding a duplicate item to the list?

My function builds the list from reading a file.

For example this is the output I want:

```
2 milk
```

instead of:

```
milk milk
```

[['eggs', 1.99], ['milk', 3.59], ['salmon', 9.99], ['bread', 3.25], ['bean dip', 2.99], ['Fat Tire Ale', 8.99], ['Greek yogurt', 4.99], ['brocoli', 2.29], ['tomatos', 3.19], ['apples', 5.99], ['chicken', 10.99], ['chips', 3.69], ['muesli', 4.99], ['Nine Lives catfood', 6.39], ['goat cheese', 5.19], ['parmesan cheese', 5.99], ['Pinot Noir', 18.5]] this is the list

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72120846/edit) the question (and use code block formatting, please) instead of posting updates in comments. You can use `collections.Counter`, the python equivalent of multiset.

Comment: So basically, you want a list with **unique** items such as "salmon", "milk" etc, but each item, which is basically a string, should have a number appended in start of it, to describe how many times each appear in the original list. So for example, you want an output list like this: `["2 milk", "1 salmon" .... ]`

Comment: yes thats what i want.

Comment: In case, an item only appears once, do you want the item to have `1` in start of it, or just its name. For example, do you want `salmon` or `1 salmon`?

Comment: 1 salmon is what i'm looking for

Comment: Writing a solution, kindly wait a few minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, for each entry in your list, you split it into two words: name and price. Since, we are only concerned with the item name, we store the value inside `entry[0]` into `item`, which is basically the name of some item. Now, we assume that this is the first time we are encountering this item, so we set `isFirst` equal to `True`.

Now, we go through each item stored in your output list: `out`. Since, each item inside `out` looks like: `COUNT NAME`, we split it, and check if current item's name is found inside this splitted string. If it does, we retrieve the value of its count and add one to it.

We now get the index of this item, set the incremented value of count to it, set the `isFirst` flag to `False`, since we are not encountering this item for the first time, and break out of the loop.

If `isFirst` was set to `True`, i.e., it was out first time encountering such item, we simply append `1 ITEM_NAME` to the output list.

```
out = []

for entry in originalList:
    item = entry[0]
    isFirst = True
    for s in out:
        if item in s.split():
            count = int(s.split()[0]) + 1
            index = out.index(s)
            out[index] = f"{count} {item}"
            isFirst = False
            break
    if isFirst:
        out.append(f"1 {item}")
```

**Some other improvements to your code**:

Try to use [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) to represent formatted strings (those where you need a variable's value inside). So, the line where you are asking for user's input, you can replace it with:

```
optionSelect = input(f"\nAdd {groceries[int(groceriesInput)- 1][0]} to the cart? (y or n):")
```